# Error: GET 404 Page not found with Nuxtjs3

Tags: vuejs3, fetch-api, nuxtjs3

I am learning nuxtjs3. I am trying to get data in the template with fetch. I am following a certain tutorial but unfortunately I am stuck.  I am using [mysql2 library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) in the app and a  mysql local database. But I am receiving **Error: GET http://localhost:3000/api/users/index 404 (Page not found: /api/users/index)** in the console. What am I doing wrong.

Below is the database.ts file

```
import mysql from 'mysql2/promise'

const db = await mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'myuser',
    password: 'mypass',
    database: "mydb"
})

export default db
```

Below is the index.ts file

```
 import type { IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } from 'http'
 import db from '~~/server/middleware/database'

 export default async (req: IncomingMessage, res:ServerResponse) => { 
 const [rows,fields] = await db.execute("SELECT * FROM clients")
 return{
     staus: res.statusCode,
     columns: fields.map((i: any) => i.name),
     entries: rows,
     message: res.statusMessage
 }
}
```

Below is the index.vue file where I want to display the data.

```
<script setup>

import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

const entries = ref([])
const setEntries = async () => {
     const response = await fetch('/api/users/index')
     const data = await response.json()
     if('entries' in data) {
        entries.value = data.entries
      }
}

onMounted(setEntries)

</script>

<template>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped mt-3">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Client Phone</th>
      <th>Client Email</th>
      
      <th style="width: 130px;">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="user in entries" :key="user.client_phone">
      <td>{{ user.client_phone }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.client_email }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</template>
```

Below is the arrangement of the files and folders of the app.

[image]

What am doing wrong to get **Error: GET 404 (Page not found: /api/users/index)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody else has responded and despite not having tried the nuxt fetch API my self, my best guess from reading the [Nitro Server Engine](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/server-engine) docs is that you should be using `$fetch` not `fetch`.

---

`fetch` is native javascript fetch API thus wont have any attribution to the application and the API endpoint your calling.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

---

`$fetch` is a nuxt wrapper for fetch and I assume will be injecting a baseURL and various headers to make it work.

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/dollarfetch#fetch

```js
const response = await $fetch('/api/users/index')
```

---

The next problem I can see is according to the [server directory](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#server-directory) docs, the export in `server/api/users/index.ts` should use `defineEventHandler`:

```js
import db from '~~/server/middleware/database'

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const [rows,fields] = await db.execute("SELECT * FROM clients")

  return {
    staus: res.statusCode,
    columns: fields.map((i: any) => i.name),
    entries: rows,
    message: res.statusMessage
  }
})
```

Comment: I have try to change `fetch()` to `$fetch()` but still gets the same response 404 Page not found. Thanks @Marc.

Comment: @GabrielRogath I added some more information I have found.

Comment: you are wright, this `defineEventHandler` was a problem